# Decimal Points in User Point Module

Tags: 7, userpoints

My client requirement is to assign user points in decimal format. Later on when user wants to credit those points in dollar at that it might go in decimal again. I Installed [User Point](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module in Drupal 7. When I was referring their api I came to know that they allow only integer points to add. I searched for the ways to make it compatible with Decimal or float. I found one suggestion saying like you can change their design of tables for that module. I would not prefer to do so. Is there any other alternate way to make this user points compatible with Decimal or Float point system. If you have any other suggestion then let me know.

Comment: Dividing the user points by 100?

Comment: You mean say to define one middle parameter which will be used to convert points from back and forth from backend to frontend. Let's say that parameter is 100. So on the backend it is stored as x points. That points can be shown as x/100 to user. Am I right?